# How to ssh via USB Ethernet adapter

Tags: arduino-galileo, ssh, connector

For a few days now, I have been connecting to my board which is hooked up to my router through a clutter of wires, over Wi-Fi. To spare my family from the risk of tripping, or hogging the extension cords all to myself, I'm looking for a way to establish an ssh connection directly from my computer (either via a USB Ethernet or a Thunderbolt Ethernet adapter).

My question is *what address* will I be looking for? Is it something like `arduinoname.local`?

Comment: Ehhm, so your Arduino is connected to your Wifi network and you are asking, what IP it has to reach it from your PC? Have you looked at the webinterface of your router? Normally there you can find a list of connected devices with their IP addresses. When your Arduino uses DHCP, the router is the one, who sets the device to a specific address. So you should look there

Comment: No, no, no! I have been connecting over Wifi, but I want to be able to connect over cable instead (computer-to-board instead of computer-to-router-to-board)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ssh root@[arduinoname].local
```

does the trick. Just replace [arduinoname] with your board's name: `ssh root@myboard.local`

Seems to take a minute or two to initialize, so if it doesn't work immediately don't give up right away!

This however won't allow you to access your internet, so I'll still have to connect to my router if I'm going to be downloading anything.